# Excel Sum across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA and hope someone can help me with this. I have create a custom function to sum the value of a cell from multiple sheets. However the cell in the sheet that I have to use the function is not the same that I need to sum. For example I need to sum B2 from all sheets but the place where I need to use the function is the cell C2. Could someone help?
My code:

```
Function AutoSum() As Variant
    AutoSum = 0
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Application.ThisCell.Parent Then AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(Application.ThisCell.Address)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Add the cell address that you want to use as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it slightly and place the range you want to sum

=autosum(d1) will sum all the D1 cells.

```
Function AutoSum(rng As Range) As Variant
    AutoSum = 0
    Application.Volatile True
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Application.ThisCell.Parent Then
            AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```